# Keeping track of the action before a login?

Tags: grails

I'm trying to do the following:

1. User can vote for an item (controller: item, action: vote)

2a. If the user is logged in, then vote action goes through.

2b. If user is not logged in, then user needs to log in/creates an account (handled by user controller), then vote action goes through.

How do I do 2b such that once the user logs in/creates account, the vote action automatically goes through without having the user vote for the item again?

Answer (score 0):

Store the users vote in the session object. When the user logs in check the session object for an existing vote. Something like the following sudo code.
vote action

```
if (isLoggedIn==false)
{
session['vote']=voteObject
}
```

And from the action executed when a user successfully logs in.

```
if(session['vote']!=null) {
//read the 'vote' object from your session and put the users vote in
}
```

Comment: Hi Jared, suppose that there are other actions (i.e. vote, comment, etc) that could also require logging in, would the action just include an if-statement for each type of action that could require a login?  Is there a more generic way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

store vote url and param into params, and pass to login action.

see also shiro plugins

Answer (score 0):

Similar to earlier suggestions, you could store the params from one or more action prior to login, but store them as an array of arrays in the session variable.  The array key value could be the action attempted with any applicable params stored within that array data.  Then post login you could check that session variable and easily process each request.